# Regular expressions in python - trouble with optional phrase

Tags: python, regex

I need a little script to filter literature references from a given text. The references can be in two formats:

bla bla bla (Snowden, 2014a) bla bla bla (Bush and Blair, 2005) bla bla bla.

Finding these references with two searches works find:

```
matches1 = re.findall('\([A-Z]\w*,\s?\d\d\d\d[a-z]?\)', line)
matches2 = re.findall('\([A-Z]\w* and [A-Z]\w*,\s?\d\d\d\d[a-z]?\)', line)
```

These searches correctly find (Snowden, 2014a) resp. (Bush and Blair, 2005). But now I want to find both kind of references in one search and it fails:

```
matches1 = re.findall('\([A-Z]\w*( and [A-Z]\w*)?,\s?\d\d\d\d[a-z]?\)', line)
```

This search returns '' instead of (Snowden, 2014a) and ' and Blair' instead of (Bush and Blair, 2005). Its not clear to me why this happens or what I've done wrong, so any help is appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just turn the capturing group to non-capturing group and reduce `\d\d\d\d` to `\d{4}`. Because `re.findall` gives the first preference to the groups. If there any groups is present, it would print only the chars present inside the groups. And it forget about the matched strings.

```
\([A-Z]\w*(?: and [A-Z]\w*)?,\s?\d{4}[a-z]?\)
```

Sample Code:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """foo bar (Snowden, 2014a)
... (Bush and Blair, 2005) foo bar"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'\([A-Z]\w*(?: and [A-Z]\w*)?,\s?\d{4}[a-z]?\)', s, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
(Snowden, 2014a)
(Bush and Blair, 2005)
```

Comment: [Accept an answer which helped you the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Make your optional group non-capturing by adding `?:`:

```
In [8]: re.findall('\([A-Z]\w*(?: and [A-Z]\w*)?,\s?\d\d\d\d[a-z]?\)', line)
Out[8]: ['(Snowden, 2014a)', '(Bush and Blair, 2005)']
```